# Randomly rotated Instance mesh along multiple trimmed curves

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

**My situation :** I have one bezier curve object with multiple lines inside it. I'm using Geometry Nodes to spawn instances of a mesh along each curve. I want to animate each curve growing, and I want instances to be spawned at regular intervals, with a scale according to their position on the curve, each having a random rotation, but while I animate the curves growing, I don't want instances to move or to rotate.

**My problem :** my setup works fine for the first curve I draw in the bezier object, but not for the concurrent ones :

[image: One curve working as intended, not the second one]

Here's my current setup :

[image: Geometry node setup]

I could always create one Bezier object for each curve but I intend to draw a lot of them so I'm trying to find a fix to my problem.